# AWS Lambda/Cognito Authentication - Assuming Auth Role

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to create an iOS app in Swift that uses the following authentication service using AWS Lambda - https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth

It uses the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS to communicate with DynamoDB and Lambda - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/

Here is the sample code for the website that utilizes the token returned from the Lambda login function, I imagine the Swift code will be something similar - https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth/blob/master/www/login.html#L69

Here is the cloud function that generates the token for the user - https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth/blob/master/LambdAuthLogin/index.js#L102

I have created an identity pool in AWS Cognito (Federated Identities) and I have two roles, auth and unauth. My application appears to always being the unauth role (arn:aws:sts::123123123:assumed-role/_unauth_MOBILEHUB_123123123/CognitoIdentityCredentials). My users are being stored in a dynamodb table, with a salted password.

The root of the problem is that I don't know the correct Swift code to write after I receive a login token from the service to transition my user into the authenticated role (use the auth arn). I want it to be using the auth role for every service call to AWS (dynamodb, lambda, etc). I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction - thank you.

Comment: any luck on this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the design in Danilo's book, if you are using the aws-sdk javascript , you should define your objects like :

```
var creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: //hard coded value for your system//
})

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: creds
});

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
```

then once you receive your identityId and token , you should assign them to you creds as follow :

```
creds.params['IdentityId'] = output.identityId;
creds.params['Logins'] = {};
creds.params['Logins']['cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'] = output.token;
creds.expired = true;
```

where output is the response from your LambdAuthLogin Lambda function.

Answer (score -1):

Authenticated roles will only be used when you use one of the supported public providers (Facebook, Google, Twitter, Login With Amazon), OIDC provider, SAML provider or Cognito User Pool users.

[Amazon Cognito User Pools](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-user-pools-for-amazon-cognito/) provides you the solution for user registration, authentication and management. Is there is reason that you prefer using Lambda Auth over that?